# Flex : Unable to open 'locale/en_US'

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flexbuilder

Using Flex Builder :
I have created a new Actionscript Project.
I want to use mx.controls.Button class in it,
so I did the following :

1. Added '-locale=en_US -source-path=locale/{locale}' to the Actionscript compiler arguments
2. Added 'framework.swc' to the library path

But now I get this error:
**unable to open 'locale/en_US'**
I looked up and I do have the following directory inside my Flex Builder 3 installation: 

./sdks/3.0.0/frameworks/locale/en_US

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added a "locale" directory containing an "en_US" directory at the root of your Flex project, to be used for storing your locale-specific properties?  For example, in a project supporting English- and French-localized strings, your Flex project structure might look something like this:

```
-- YourProject
   |-- libs
   |-- locale
       |-- en_US
           |-- resources.properties
       |-- en_FR
           |-- resources.properties
   |-- src
       |-- [Your source files...]
```

Sounds like that might be what's happening.  Give it a try and post back if it doesn't work for ya.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem

> Try using this compiler argument:
>
> -locale en_US de_DE -source-path+=../locale/{locale}
>
> change de_DE to your locale name.

Above answer worked well..
just add `+=../locale{locale}`

Answer (score 2):

Try using this compiler argument:

```
-locale en_US de_DE -source-path+=../locale/{locale}
```

change `de_DE` to your locale name.

Answer (score 2):

To address the said issue, go to this path:
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64
Bit)\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexbuilder.flexunit_4.7.0.349722\flexunitSwcs\4.5\locale\en_U
S
You will see a FlexUnitTestRunner_rb.swc file on the said path.
Create a new folder named “version4locale” under the said path and copy and paste the
FlexUnitTestRunner_rb.swc to the newly created folder. You will end up with the path :
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64
Bit)\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexbuilder.flexunit_4.7.0.349722\flexunitSwcs\4.5\locale\en_U
S\version4locale\ having FlexUnitTestRunner_rb.swc file as well.

Source:- https://geekabanga.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/upgrading-flash-builder-4-7-air-sdk-3-7.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Put locales to sdks\3.2.0\frameworks\locale\en_US
it works well also.