# mxmlc Error: Unable to resolve resource bundle "X" for locale "y" : ANT build issues

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, ant, localization, flex4.5

I know there are tons of similar questions and answers for this topic, but I am still having the same issue.  So far, I've looked at [this](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2671191), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666310/flex-and-ant-resource-bundle-error), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108065/unable-to-resolve-resource-bundle-for-locale-en-us-flex-flash-builder), [this](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Easily_compile_resource_bundles_using_Ant-12765.html), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028644/flex-unable-to-open-locale-en-us), etc....  To no avail.

I always get this error when I try to run an ANT build on my project.

```
    [mxmlc] Error: Unable to resolve resource bundle "resources" for locale "en_US".

BUILD FAILED
C:\***\flashWorkspace\shop\build.xml:8: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\***\flashWorkspace\Scripts\flex-build.xml:50: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\***\flashWorkspace\Scripts\flex-build.xml:123: mxmlc task failed
```

My build.xml:

```
<target name="compile" depends="common-build.compile">
    <antcall target="flex-build.compile-air-application"/>   // line 8
</target>
```

Which brings us to my flex-build.xml (this is where I'll be calling the macro that throws the error):

```
<target name="compile-air-application">
    <compileSWF>      // line 50
        <compiler-options>
            <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/air-config.xml"/>
        </compiler-options>
    </compileSWF>            
</target>
```

And finally, the macro itself that contains the erroneous mxmlc call:

```
<macrodef name="compileSWF">
    <element name="compiler-options" optional="yes"/>
    <attribute name="sourceDir" default="${src.dir}"/>
    <attribute name="libraryDir" default="${build.lib.dir}"/>
    <attribute name="buildDir" default="${build.dir}"/>
    <attribute name="locale" default="${locale}"/>
    <attribute name="applicationFile" default="${application.file}"/>
    <attribute name="outputFile" default="${swf.file}"/>
    <sequential>
        <delete file="@{buildDir}/@{outputFile}"/>
        <mxmlc file="@{sourceDir}/@{applicationFile}" output="@{buildDir}/@{outputFile}" locale="@{locale}">          //line 123
            <compiler-options/>
            <source-path path-element="@{sourceDir}"/>
            <compiler.library-path dir="@{libraryDir}" append="true">
                <include name="*.swc"/>
            </compiler.library-path>
        </mxmlc>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

These are my compiler arguments:

```
-locale=en_US,fr_FR -source-path=locale/{locale}
```

And basically my folder structure is like this

```
Proj 
  |-- src 
  |-- lib 
  |-- locale 
          |-- en_US
               |-- resources.properties     
          |-- fr_FR 
               |-- resources.properties
```

Can anyone see what's wrong with my ANT build?  If you need any more information I'll be happy to edit and add them to the post.  I've tried a myriad of hacks that I've found on the net: I've been trying to resolve this all day :/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI for anyone else having this problem, fixed by adding these two directives :

```
            **<source-path>locale/{locale}</source-path>
            <include-resource-bundles>resources</include-resource-bundles>**
```

so the mxmlc looks like this

```
<mxmlc file="@{sourceDir}/@{applicationFile}" output="@{buildDir}/@{outputFile}" locale="@{locale}">
    <compiler-options/>
    <source-path>locale/{locale}</source-path>
    <include-resource-bundles>resources</include-resource-bundles>
    <source-path path-element="@{sourceDir}"/>
    <compiler.library-path dir="@{libraryDir}" append="true">
        <include name="*.swc"/>
    </compiler.library-path>
</mxmlc>
```